# c# How to cast object to type dynamically?

Tags: c#

In the following sample code, I want to set street property to a value dynamically:

```
public static dynamic Cast(dynamic obj, Type castTo) => Convert.ChangeType(obj, castTo);

public Type GetType(string typeName) => assemblies.Select(a => a.GetType(typeName)).FirstOrDefault(type => type != null);

private void UpdateAddress()

{

   var manager = Cast(companyObj.Manager, GetType("Namespace.Manager"));

   var addressProperty = manager.GetType().GetProperty("Address", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

   var address = Cast(addressProperty, GetType("Namespace.Address"));

   var street= address.GetType().GetProperty("Street", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
   street.SetValue(address, "Bank Str", null);

}
```

I need to cast addressProperty to type "Namespace.Address" in order to be able to load the property "Street" from the object, but it fails, because addressProperty is of type dynamic.

Comment: casting is a **compile**-time thing. You can´t expect the compiler to know anything about a type you provide at **runtime**. Best you can do is to extract an interface from your class and cast to that interface.

Comment: Why do you want this in the first place? Why not use generics instead of `dynamic`? Or just use the classes and properties you have? Whatever the real problem is, there are probably easier ways to fix it. Including *not* using `dynamic`. If you want to create a plugin architecture nothing forces you to ditch types

Comment: I agree Pana: usually when you want to have something dynamic, you don´t use `dynamic` for it. You surely have some idea of your types, e.g. through some base-interface that all your classes implement.

Comment: If you can hard-code the type names in a string, you already know what those types are at compile time. You can create interfaces with just the members you want and have your plugins implement them. This makes finding the types a lot easier too. This is so common that DI Containers like AutoFac can scan all loaded assemblies and inject types and interfaces

Comment: That is because we have to generate some controls dynamically and set values on objects dynamically, and persist objects dynamically. So we get to know classes and properties at runtime.

Comment: I'm not saying that `dynamic` is evil per say, but it has a very limited set of justified use-cases - and almost every time I've seen someone using `dynamic` it was for the wrong reasons. Note: I'm also not saying `generics` is a the solution here - because I'm not even sure what the problem is - however one thing is clear - the solution is probably not `dynamic`. (I'm taking 99% or higher probability here)

Comment: Well, even if you do not use strong typing, your rely on the properties anyway. So if you already know that your obj must have some `manager` and an `adress`, why not create an interface that reflects exactly those propertes and methods you need to access?

Comment: Good idea HimBromBeere. It seems that I cannot do it 100% dynamically. Thanks!

Comment: just use var address = addressProperty as  Namespace.Address; and then access properties directly

Comment: All the quibbling over the use of `dynamic` is trivial because the code is orders of magnitude worse for how it uses strings to resolve types.

Comment: Why you need any cast at all? It's a dynamic, you can already access to any of it's properties through late binding, that's what dynamic is for... `string street = companyObj.Manager.Address.Street;` should work.

Comment: well, you **can** do it completely dynamic. In that case you need some reflection-based approach and maybe even `dynamic`. The question should be? **Do you really need to** do have this flexibility, which the answer is usally - as also pointed by Zolar Peled: no.

Comment: It could be nice, if I could do it completely dynamically. It will try to find a reflection-based approach HimBromBeere.

Comment: I have changed the method to: public static T Cast<T>(object obj, Type castTo) => (T) Convert.ChangeType(obj, castTo); And I use reflection now to find the class.